# 'Fetch as Google' in Webmaster tool says 'Redirected'

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Google webmaster tool shows me this for my website. https://ibb.co/cnCOfk

This is a WP website, and my guess is it's because the redirection from non-www to www is not happening. Google fetches with www and then my website gets redirect too non-www domain. How do I fix this problem?

I found online that I can solve this with .htaccess. Now, I added last 2 lines (above IfModle ends). Currently, my .htaccess looks like this.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Once I add this, website goes in infinite loop of "www.domainname.co" to "domainname.co" to "www.domainname.co" and so on.

How do I solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem this redirect is occurring within WordPress itself - that is where you need to fix this. You can then repeat the same redirect in `.htaccess` if you wish, as that would be more efficient.

But if you do the *opposite* redirect in `.htaccess` then you'll naturally get a redirect loop.

**EDIT:** And if you implement this redirect in `.htaccess`, it should go *before* the WordPress *front controller*.